# What are the specific guidelines in driving from state to state during this pandemic?

Tags: usa, driving, covid-19, restricted-areas

April 7, 2020

Can you provide me any information about the travel restrictions in driving from state to state during this pandemic? There are curfews and businesses closing early, does this affect the gas stations throughout the United States that you find a long the highways? I'm thinking this would even cause loss of business or loss of business with truck rentals like Uhaul or Budget. I've not contacted them yet but thought I'd include that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where are you planning to drive to/from? And, most importantly, why? Stay at home!

Comment: @jcaron - there are many possible valid reasons to be driving. For example, students who have remained near campus (perhaps for great wifi in their apartment to keep up on the online course delivery) for the rest of the semester but need to get home once their lease expires.

Comment: There are also many rural areas near state lines where the nearest grocery store, bank, or hospital may be in another state, but asking about all of those cases is certainly too broad for this site.

Answer (score 2):

Stay home if your travel is non-essential.

That being said, travelling is *still* not prohibited in the USA.

Most gas stations are open as they are an essential service.

When arriving to your destination, stay in self-quarantine for at least 14 days, whether or not you have symptoms.

Some states have guidelines in regards to travelling, for example [Maine](https://www.usatoday.com/story/travel/news/2020/04/04/coronavirus-travel-restrictions-us-states-quarantine-requirements/2947021001/) ask for a 14 quarantine ...

Comment: You make it sound as if the lack of a national travel ban is a failure. An interstate ban would do little to halt the spread of the virus beyond existing stay-at-home orders, and would be utterly unenforceable not only for lack of manpower but for its dubious legality and universal unpopularity across the political spectrum. Even the idea of cordoning off the area around New York City, the hardest hit place in the hemisphere, was criticized so harshly that the White House backed off the idea instead of doubling down per their usual MO.

Comment: (personally) in a way yes; there should have been a more stiff recomendation against traveling; but here is not the place to debate that.